# How to access the checkbox data in Django form

Tags: checkbox, django-forms, django-1.9

I have a few checkboxes in my Django form. After a user selects a particular checkbox, I want to know which all checkboxes were selected by the user. I can see the first name, last name, username, and email of the user in the Django admin, that the user provides while filling up the form, but I can't see which checkboxes did the user select.

How can I access the Checkbox's data? I know I need to do some modifications in my code for that, so please suggest me the modifications in my code. I'm using Django 1.9.I went through some materials online and the documentation as well, but couldn't understand much.

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from volunteer.models import UserProfileInfo

NGO_CHOICES = (
('one', 'ONE'),
('two', 'TWO'),
('three', 'THREE'),)

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
ngo = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, 
choices=NGO_CHOICES)

class Meta():
    model = User
    fields = ('ngo','email','first_name','last_name','username')
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from volunteer.forms import UserForm



def register(request):

registered = False

if request.method =="POST" :
    user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)

    if user_form.is_valid():
        ngo = user_form.cleaned_data['ngo'] #getting the list of the ngos. 

        user = user_form.save()

        user.save()

        registered = True

    else:
        print(user_form.errors)

else:
    user_form = UserForm()

return render(request, 'volunteer/volunteer.html',
                         {'user_form':user_form,
                          'registered':registered})
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfileInfo(models.Model):

    user=models.OneToOneField(User)

    def __str__(self):
            return self.user.first_name
            return self.user.last_name
            return self.user.email
            return self.user.ngo
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from volunteer.models import UserProfileInfo

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(UserProfileInfo)
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

app_name = 'volunteer'

urlpatterns = [

 url(r'^', views.register, name='register'),
 ]
```

volunteer.html(which has the form)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">


<meta name="viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">




</head>      

<body>   

 <div class="jumbotron">
    {% if registered %}
       <p>Thank you.<p>

    {% else %}
      <h1>Register yourself for Volunteering</h1>




 <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ user_form.as_p }}
 <input type="submit" name="" value="Register as a Volunteer">

 {% endif %}

 </div> 


 </form>

</body>
</html>
```

NOTE - I haven't included bootstrap, ajax and jquery libraries in the above HTML code due to formatting issues, I don't think they have anything to do with the problem, so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access in your view all data from your forms.
Just print request.POST to see wich checkbox is selected.